# Swift structures properties is the same type as structure it self. Recursion?

Tags: swift, structure, static-members, getter

Please help me to understand the following Swift construction:

```
struct UIViewAnimationOptions : RawOptionSetType {
    init(_ rawValue: UInt)
    init(rawValue rawValue: UInt)
    static var LayoutSubviews: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
    static var AllowUserInteraction: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
    static var BeginFromCurrentState: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
    static var Repeat: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
    static var Autoreverse: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
    static var OverrideInheritedDuration: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
}
```

I don't understand how structure properties could be of the same type as the structure itself. And for what purpose all getters are empty? How this thing even works?
Here is the brief example how I using this structure for animation in my code:

```
let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat
...
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: options, animations: {
...
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This explains it perfectly well: http://nshipster.com/rawoptionsettype/

Comment: Thanks, but, frankly speaking, I understand a little from this article and couldn't find any plain answers to my questions :( Could you please give me some more hints? Step by step...Why getters are empty as if it was a protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are `static` properties, which are not associated with an instance of the struct. (Plus, the properties may be computed or stored; you don't know. And it's possible to have a struct have a computed instance property of its own type.)

Comment: Thanks. I understand that struct could have a computed static property of its own type. But still some questions left. Why there is no any implementations in this structure? Initializers declared but not implemented, all getters are empty. How this should work?

Comment: @ФедорУсаков: It's implemented by Apple and you don't see their source code. (Actually it's implemented in Objective-C and imported into Swift with some modifications.) You only see a generated "header" if you will. Those properties are actually stored, not computed, but to the outsider there is no difference.

Comment: Thanks! I gave to much trust to Apple documentation  :)